# Form data appearing 2 times in console on one click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I am trying to create a login form but it shows the form values 2 times in console at one click and i am not sure where the error was can any one find the error....

my template

```
  div class="login jumbotron center-block">
 <h1>Login</h1>
 <form  #form ="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="username">Username</label>
  <input type="text" ngControl ="email" class="form-control" id="emailh" placeholder="Username">
   </div>
 <div class="form-group">
   <label for="password">Password</label>
   <input type="password"  ngControl ="phone" class="form-control" id="phoneh" placeholder="Password">
 </div>
 <button   class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>

 </form>
  </div>
```

my component

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
  import { Router, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';
  import { CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/common';
  import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
  import { contentHeaders } from '../headers/headers';
  import {Control,FormBuilder,ControlGroup,Validators} from '@angular/common';


  @Component({

  directives: [ ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES ],
  templateUrl : "./components/login/login.html",

 })
 export class Login {

 constructor(public router: Router, public http: Http) {
 }

 onSubmit(form:any) {

     console.log(form);
}
  }
```

I am trying to create a login form but it shows the form values 2 times in console at one click and i am not sure where the error was can any one find the error....

Comment: It's once only http://embed.plnkr.co/w2FVfKlWP72pzXIsfsCU/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need disable the old forms module

```
import {disableDeprecatedForms, provideForms} from '@angular/forms';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [disableDeprecatedForms(), provideForms()]);
```

and import forms-related stuff only from `@angular/forms` instead of `@angular/common`